# Change certificate and certificate name using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to copy (overwrite) a certificate using Ansible. Now that shouldn't be too hard, but after that I want to change the name of the file to the hostname Ansible is connecting to. So lets say Ansible is connecting to the host `myserver.datacenter.com` which is in the Ansible hosts file, I want it to change the certificate name to `myserver.datacenter.com-cert.pem` and `myserver.datacenter.com-key.pem`.

I got the file to copy over, but I'm not sure how to change the file name to the hosts name.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you like to copy the files over to the Remote Node and change the filenames of the target files only.

To do so, you can just use [`copy` module – Copy files to remote locations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) and [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: myserver.example.com
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Copy Private Key to Remote Node
    copy:
      src: private.key
      dest: "/etc/pki/tls/private/{{ inventory_hostname }}.key"

  - name: Copy Certificate to Remote Node
    copy:
      src: certificate.pem
      dest: "/etc/pki/tls/certs/{{ inventory_hostname }}.pem"
```

**Further Reading**

- [Ansible: How to get hostname ...](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17139/6017)

Comment: When I use ansible_nodename, it's using the hostname of the machine. The hostname of the machine is different than the DNS name I use in my hosts file. I need the name of the file to change to the DNS name used in the hosts file.

Comment: Regarding "_The hostname of the machine is different than the DNS name I use in my hosts file._", this is something which should never happen. However, as mentioned within the linked further reading you could then just use the `inventory_hostname`.

Comment: Yes I agree it's not best practice, but indeed using inventory_hostname solves my problem. Thank you